# Как получить значение объекта используя значение из другого объекта js

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте как получить значения объекта используя значением из другого объекта? грубо говоря buy_groups.groups.group_id на php это выглядело б так: `$buy_groups[$groups['group_id']]` Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: точно также: `buy_groups[groups.group_id]`

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо, не смог нормально сформулировать запрос в гугле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получение поля объекта в JavaScript делается двумя способами.

Через точку

```
a.b - поле b объекта a
```

Через квадратные скобочки

```
a['b'] - тоже самое что a.b
```

Во втором случае в качестве аргумента скобочек может использоваться переменная.

Поэтому ваш пример можно решить так

```
buy_groups[groups.group_id]
```

либо так

```
buy_groups[groups['group_id']]
```

первый вариант более красивый.

Код для теста

```js
var a = { b: 5, c: "hi"};
var par = 'b';

console.log(a.b);
console.log(a['b']);
console.log(a[par]);
```